# WPF Context Menu MenuItem with a Command plus submenu using ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, menuitem

I'm adding some functionality to a context menu in a wpf control we have. We originaly had a MenuItem like this

```xaml
<MenuItem Command="{Binding topCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding arg}"/>
```

Next I want to add a dropdown menu when you mouseover, each of those items has its own command that gets called.

```xml
<MenuItem Command="{Binding topCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding arg}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding subCommands}"/>
```

Now, subCommands are showing up correctly and clicking on them calls the right command. However, topCommand (an ICommand) is never getting Executed. Weird thing is its CanExecute IS being called and returns true! The item is enabled but nothing is happening on click. Using snoop I can see my Command and CommandParameter are properly bound on the MenuItem.

Is it possible to have both a command and a submenu on a MenuItem?